# Cannot set default printer

Tags: printer

I use Garuda linux and HP printer. When I click "print" from a document viewer, it works. When I type `lp -d <printer_name> example.pdf`, it works.

But `lp example.pdf` returns `lp: Error - No default destination.` And `sudo lpadmin -d <printer_name>` returns `lpadmin: The printer or class does not exist.`

Why is this the case? The printer's name is recognized when I use it with `lp`, but not when I try to set it as default. How do I set the default printer so that `lp example.pdf` just works?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04.3 I'd somehow corrupted my printing configuration.  By trial and error I restored it:

`lpstat -e` discovered my printer_name.
`sudo systemctl start cups-browsed`
`lpq -P my_printer_name`
`lpadmin -d` still failed, but that didn't matter.
`lpq`, `lpr`, and `lp` resumed working with no `-d` or `-P` needed.  But I don't know why.

An uglier solution:  in ~/.bashrc, `alias lp='lp -d my_printer_name'`.